# Parsing JSON With Newtonsoft Throwing Incorrect Format Error

Tags: c#, json

I am attempting to parse my JSON response by taking the response and copy/paste it into Json2CSharp then adding the 2 newly generated classes to the bottom of my current class.  (I do not like dealing with multiple classes).  The issue that I am having is that when I attempt to access the generated class `RootObject` I get an error of

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Test.RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Even though the syntax was converted for me, and I did not change it.  What do I need to alter so that this becomes valid workable syntax?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string userid= "186exa";
    var url = "https/?rst=" + userid;

    var connectionClient = new WebClient();
    connectionClient.Headers.Set("H", "XXXXXXXXXXXX");
    connectionClient.Headers.Set("uname", "user");
    connectionClient.Headers.Set("pswd", "pwd");
    var content = connectionClient.DownloadString(url);
}
```

**EDIT**
This is the class - will post the JSON shortly

```
    public class List
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string cmu { get; set; }
    public int lno { get; set; }
    public string clr { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string origin { get; set; }
    public string MajorStyle { get; set; }
    public string Style { get; set; }
    public string styleImage { get; set; }
    public int hid { get; set; }
    public string bqty { get; set; }
    public int cask { get; set; }
    public int local { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string style { get; set; }
    public List<List> List { get; set; }
}
```

This is the retunred JSON

```
[{"Style":"Cajun","List":[{"id":1225,"cmu":"41.2","lno":10,"name":"Bear","origin":"Lake Sinclair, MO","MajorStyle":"Burn Yo Bottom","Style":"","styleImage":"","hid":1,"bqty":"1.00","cask":0,"local":0,"city":"Amsterdam"}
```

Comment: This code is of no use to the question, please provide the classes and the JSON.

Comment: Please post an example of your JSON response.

Comment: @Simon - updated post to include requested info.

Comment: @Sxntk - Response has been addeed.

Comment: @YohanGreenburg You have an array of `RootObject[]` not a `RootObject` and an array of `List[]` (it doesn't make a lot of sense) not a `List<T>`

Comment: @Sxntk -> how can I return the response from that?  I have no way of altering the JSON response just have to find a way to read it and parse it.

Comment: @YohanGreenburg Please edit your answer with the relevant code only and rewording the question, because what you need is to read the JSON response not to fix the Incorrect format error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things at fault with the code you have posted,

1. The property "clr" does not exist in the JSON.
2. The JSON ends prematurely, it should have ]}] on the end to be correct.

Fixing both of those issues, the code parses correctly in Newtonsoft when passing it the type RootObject[], as per:

```
var o = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(s);
```

Where s is the JSON string.

Comment: How would I then extract info from the variable o?

Comment: The variable is of type RootObject[], in this case where there is only one item in the list you could use o[0].Style, o[0].List[0].id for example. In the case where there are multiple items in the list you would have to iterate through.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need your classes match with your JSON response, so your classes should look like

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Style { get; set; }

    public List[] List { get; set; }
}

public class List
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string cmu { get; set; }
    public int lno { get; set; }
    public string clr { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string origin { get; set; }
    public string MajorStyle { get; set; }
    public string Style { get; set; }
    public string styleImage { get; set; }
    public int hid { get; set; }
    public string bqty { get; set; }
    public int cask { get; set; }
    public int local { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
}
```

After that you need to map the response to an object

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; // Need this to work with JsonConvert

string json = @"[
    {
    'Style':'Cajun',
    'List':
        [
            {
                'id':1225,
                'cmu':'41.2',
                'lno':10,
                'name':'Bear',
                'origin':'Lake Sinclair, MO',
                'MajorStyle':'Burn Yo Bottom',
                'Style':'',
                'styleImage':'',
                'hid':1,
                'bqty':'1.00',
                'cask':0,
                'local':0,
                'city':'Amsterdam'
            }
        ]
    }
]";
RootObject[] response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(json);
```

Using the keyword List could lead you to mistakes, because there is also a class for C# called List, so be careful.